# Django rest framework, trying to customize the browsable API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django rest framework and I'm trying to customize one of the API's browsable API but I can't seem to be able to refer to it in the HTML File.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load rest_framework %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Second GDT Options</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="{% url 'secondgdt' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

secondgdt/urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from .views import PointsViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'secondgdt', PointsViewSet, basename='secondgdt')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),

]
```

This code raises the following error when running the server:

```
NoReverseMatch at /secondgdt/
Reverse for 'secondgdt' not found. 'secondgdt' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

setting.py

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'triangulationapi.urls'
```

triangulationapi/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
                  path('', include('landingpage.urls')),
                  path('', include('threelocationstrian.urls')),
                  path('', include('find_second_gdt.urls')),
                  path('', include('KnownLocation.urls')),
              ] + staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

I tried changing the URL reference to 'find_second_gdt', 
It resulted in the same.

Comment: where does ROOT_URLCONF from settings point?

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea I will add it

Answer (score 0):

If that app is your main one, add

```
ROOT_URLCONF = "secondgdt.urls"
```

to `settings.py`

---

If you have a main `urls.py` for multiple apps, link to that and from that one, redirect to `secondgdt.urls`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^secondgdt/", include("secondgdt.urls"))
]
```